# C++: What is the fastest way to maintain an ordered table of ip address

Tags: c++, algorithm, dns

This is the problem i am encountering:

1. A DNS query results in a list of ip address in a random order. Fo
   ex, if there are 4 address, querying 2 times results in 4 address
   coming in different order.
2. Now the requirement is to set up an ordered table which can access the addresses in O(1).
3. Potential solution would be order the ip address each time. So for ex, if 2, 1, 7, 4 is received, we can sort it and result is always 1, 2, 4, 7 and by putting the ip address in a vector, we can index it with O(1)
4. The issue arises when the DNS results in 5 address, lets say the new address is 3. Now 3 will be added in between the table and ordering is screwed up since the 3rd element should be 4. We will need to add the new elements at the end of the table
5. Deletion of element also needs to be handled gracefully, having an empty table slot can cause the problem.

Can this be done with O(1) or worst O(logn)

The problem is to maintain an ordering of IP addresses every time an ordered list is given as an input

Comment: How about `std::set` with your custom comparison, it is ordered and has lookup penalty of O(log n)?

Comment: Thanks..what should be the comparison? is it if the element is new and not present in the set?

Comment: The largest number of IP addresses returned in a DNS packet I have ever seen (and I worked writing DNS testing software for five years) is in the mid-twenties. What kind of extremely limited environment are you working with, where the difference in O(1) and O(n*log n) for that few items is even measurable?

Comment: Right, Even n(logn) is acceptable. The reason for having the server table is because millions of clients needs to get the server ip. If this is n * logn and not O(1) it might not be desirable

Comment: Now this is starting to smell like an A->B problem. What are you *actually* trying to do? Looking up things in short lists of 32- or 128-bit integers is almost certainly not it.

Comment: I am trying to implement deterministic way to stick client ip to server ip .
This means, client for multiple connections needs to be attached to a particulr ip in the server pool. This server pool are DNS queried ordered ip address. I need to maintain the ordering so that removal/addition of address  will not impact the stickiness.  More details here:
http://blog.haproxy.com/2013/04/22/client-ip-persistence-or-source-ip-hash-load-balancing/

Comment: The standard container which has O(1) lookup is the std::unordered_map. However the question does not contain enough information for me to be able to say whether this is right for your needs.

Comment: Does the table actually have to be in order, or do you just O(1) addition, lookup, and deletion? I see nothing in your requirements saying that you must be able to list the addresses in order.

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <cassert>

struct ip_address
{
  ip_address(std::initializer_list<std::uint8_t> il)
  {
    auto max = std::min(il.size(),_ip4_data.size()); 
    assert(max == 4);
    std::copy_n(il.begin(), max, _ip4_data.begin());
  }
  auto& data() const { return _ip4_data; }
  auto& data() { return _ip4_data; }
  const uint8_t& operator[](std::size_t i) const {
    return _ip4_data[i];
  }
  std::array<std::uint8_t, 4> _ip4_data;
};

bool operator==(const ip_address& l, const ip_address& r)
{
  return l.data() == r.data();
}

namespace std
{
  template<> struct hash<ip_address> {
    std::size_t operator()(const ip_address& r) const
    {
      // reverse the byte order so that the lsb of the ip
      // has the greatest effect on the hash value
      return std::size_t((r[3] << 24) & 0xff000000 
                         + (r[2] << 16) & 0x00ff0000
                         + (r[1] << 8) & 0x0000ff00
                         + r[0] & 0x000000ff); 
    }
  };
}


using client_server_map = std::unordered_map<ip_address, ip_address>;

int main()
{
  client_server_map cs_map;

  cs_map.emplace(ip_address{10, 0, 0, 1}, ip_address{192, 168, 0, 1});
  cs_map.emplace(ip_address{10, 0, 0, 2}, ip_address{192, 168, 0, 2});
  cs_map.erase(ip_address{10, 0, 0, 1});
}
```